# How to write a cancel confirmation window in php

Tags: php

Hi I have a table of bookings to be cancel but I would like to get a cancel confirmation window prompt before it can be cancelled.

I have the following code and what codes do I need to add in the line to get cancel confirmation?

```
if((($row['Event_status'] == 'Over')){
echo "<td><a href='CustPortal.php?booking_id=".$row['Booking_id']."'> Cancel</a></td>";
```

Comment: Hi im not sure about this

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript for this:

```html
<a href="cancel.php" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Cancel link</a>
```

If you want nice alerts, have a look at [SweetAlert](https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

Comment: You only have to add the "onclick" tag to your link.